# Relative degree of a Cartier divisor

Tags: algebraic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry

Let $X \to Y$ be a morphism of schemes. Let $ D \subset X$ be a closed subscheme. $D$ is called a relative effective Cartier divisor if $D$ is effective and $D \to Y$ is flat.

What is the "relative degree" of a (Cartier) divisor? How is it defined?

This terminology I found in "Higher Genus Curves in Mathematical Physics and Arithmetic Geometry" (by Andreas Malmendier, Tony Shaska) page 217. it used also in "Twelve points on the projective line, branched covers, and rational elliptic fibrations" by Ravi Vakil.

Comment: When asking for an explanation of a piece of terminology, it is best to include context like where you saw it introduced. Please add this to your question.

Comment: I added two sources where I found the terminology for the first time but seems to be used frequently in papers dealing with moduli problems

Comment: Unless the morphism $X\to Y$ is of relative dimension at most one, your definition of relative Cartier divisor is not correct. As an example, take $X=Y\times Z$ where $\dim Z\geq 2$ and let $D=Y\times\{p\}$ for a point $p\in Z$.

Comment: I'm still not quite familiar with this terminology.  Why is your example a conterexample. Looking at codimension your $D$ is not a divisor. I used the definition 31.18.2 in https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/056P